# ERROR: File 'filename.diawilink' does not exist jenkins android

Tags: android, email, jenkins, apk, diawi

I configured jenkins and diawi plugin successfully and the apk are uploaded to diawi by using jenkins.

But i am not able to send Diawi link to email via Editable Email Notification. my diawi plugin version is 1.4. I got the below error.

ERROR: File 'filename.diawilink' does not exist.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax2He.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you (only with .ipa file). I believe that v1.4 has a bug with the link display method. I reverted back to v1.3 (which you can download here: https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/diawi-upload/) and it worked. Just don't forget to use ${FILE,path=“DIAWI_LINKS”}.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the auther of that Jenkins Diawi plugin, Here is it how it works in 1.4

if the file that you are uploading to diawi.com called abcd.ipa, then inside the mail notification plugin you use this syntax
${FILE,path="abcd.ipa.diawilink"}

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in version 1.5 this syntax no longer works. It was not possible to roll back to version 1.4. This version throws an error "Unexpected response status: 400ERROR: Unexpected response status: 400"

Comment: Could you provide the correct syntax to complete the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, the author of the plugin has not yet answered me anywhere, which syntax is now correct